# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException :The value is not set for the parameter number 4

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans-8

I am facing the above-mentioned error in the following code. Please help me to fix this.

```
private void But_AddIncomeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databasename=DB_Project;user=User;Password=password";
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        String query = "insert into tbl_Reg(FullName,CNIC,Email_Address,Pswd,Adrs,PhoneNo)values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString (1,((JTextField)DateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
        pst.setString(2,Amnt_TF.getText());
        pst.setString(3,Src_TF.getText());
        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Income Detail Updated");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query has 6 parameters (6 `?` in SQL) but you set only 3 (with `setString()` method).
You need to set all 6 to avoid this exception.